# Build graph-oriented visual editor on jquery

Tags: jquery, editor, graph

We need to build the javascript-based visual editor (on jQuery) which should edit some graph-represented model. Entities should be represented as nodes and will have properties. Nodes (or/and their properties) should be linked to other nodes. Nodes should be draggable.

Are there any tutorials and jQuery plugins which can ease the development?

Thanks.

UPD: Probably draggable nodes can be implemented with the help of jQueryUI. The main problem is to implement links.

UPD2: Seems like [jsgraphics](http://www.walterzorn.com/jsgraphics/jsgraphics_e.htm) solves the problem somehow. But it does in a very inventive way and has nothing related to jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny thing... we just implemented a jQuery **Plugin** that has the purpose to ease the implementation of graph editors. However, it is not officially published yet. (we use SVG by the way - we had to, was a semester project).

You can try it out [here](http://www.nano-dimension.de/graphenzeichner/jmod/). (No IE support (SVG, as mentioned), and kind of beta). You can drag the nodes from the Shape box to the canvas. To draw connectors, click on the yellow helmet in the top menu and drag a connector between two nodes.

If this comes close to your requirements, feel free to have a look at the [sources](http://www.nano-dimension.de/graphenzeichner/jmod/lib/jquery.jmod.js).

Comment: Nice idea.
Thanks for tip about canvas and absence of it's support in IE!

Answer (score 0):

This [page](http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/20-fresh-javascript-data-visualization-libraries/) has a few links to different graph-libs including jquery-libs

Comment: Thanks but they are data visualisation related.

Answer (score 0):

We have used the free version of FusionCharts for the past year for basic graphs, and now require an editable graph.

I have just come across this [demo (adjust the bar chart sizes)](http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/features/#visual-editing-of-data)

It says also available for line chart and area chart.

They call it **Visual editing of data**.

Looks like we have to upgrade to the full version, but it certainly is what we are looking for, and I thought anyone else wanting a built-in library solution would be interested.

Call back is to javascript function, which you can then edit with jQuery (presumably for ajax, which is what we'll be doing).